Deployment start up file to App Service doesn't work
I am trying to deploy my custom startup script to App Service following the CLI command mentioned in the documentation.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip#deploy-a-startup-script
After running the command I got Jason response without any errors. I executed : aż webapp deploy --resource-group my-group --name my-app --src-path startupfiles/my-app-startup-file.sh --type=startup --target-path=/home/site/wwwroot/
Then I checked in server using Kudu tools (connected with SSH) and couldn't find the script which I expected to see in /home/site/wwwroot/ directory.
Maybe I did something wrong?
Thanks in advance!
I tried to connect to the server and check if the startup file deployed successfully, but I couldn't find it.

Have you checked whether you are able to access the APP URL first. @Vagharshak Avetisyan

I added a startup file by manually creating it in the server in the mentioned directory and application up and running without issue. The problem is that I would like to deploy the script using CLI rather than creating it myself in the server

Have you tried setting the az webapp config set --startup-file? @Vagharshak Avetisyan

In fact, the startup file was deployed totally in different directory home/site/scripts/startup.sh despite that I mentioned the target path --target-path=/home/site/wwwroot/ ..Why is that? no idea...
So, it turned out that I looked in the wrong directory..

I have created a sample node js project and added a startup.sh text file in the same path where the app configuration is present.

After that, I have added below pip install sample command as shown below.

Once it is done, I have given the same command as you and was able to view the output as expected.
az webapp deploy --resource-group "xxxx" --name "linuxnodeapp" --src-path "/home/pathofstartupfile/startup.sh.txt" --type=s
tartup --target-path=xxxxx




Note: Check the startup.sh is in the same directory path of the deploying application.
If still the issue persists, try adding the below configuration setting under an app service and execute the above process as detailed.
az webapp config appsettings set --resource-group "xxxx" --name "linuxnodeapp" --settings CUSTOM_SCRIPT_PATH=/home
/site/scripts/startup.sh.txt



I just wonder what is the value of  --target-path=xxxxx ??? According to documentation the target path by default has home/site/wwwroot/startup.sh
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli#deploy-individual-files
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/deploy-zip?tabs=cli#kudu-publish-api-reference
Eventually, I found the startup.sh in home/site/scripts/startup.sh, but why?
What's the point to look there if the default is totally different directory...

As we are deploying it as a bash script file, it is deploying in a scripts file rather than root directory. @VagharshakAvetisyan

Thanks for the explanation. Not sure, but I would like to see this in the documentation(explanation), so as not to be misled, but it's a different story.
One more time, thank you for shedding light on this @Jahnavi
